# i am getting 405 on rest assured get request but its working fine on Post man

Tags: rest-assured

[image]

Post man is giving me perfect 200 ok response but when i write this code of rest asssured i got 405 response

Comment: 405 is method not allowed, post your complete rest assured code and we can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong my friend. This is how ideally Rest-Assured is used.

```
Response response = RestAssured.given ()
  .baseUri ("<endPoint>") // The hidden part of the sample you shared.
  .basePath ("/rest/onboarding/profile")
  .contentType (ContentType.JSON)
  .queryParam ("user_id", 11)
  .when ()
  .get ("/load_user_profile");

System.out.println (response.statusCode ());
System.out.println (response.statusLine ());
```

Try this sample and let me know if this works for you as the same works for me.